# Add network engineering on the list of the on-topic page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope

When reviewing close votes, I saw a topic asking for how to compute the number of address in a network with the CNDIR notation. That question had closed flags redirecting to Super User. In my opinion, that question belongs to http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com . What I think is that those users may not be aware that the site exists.

I noticed that network engineering wasn't on the on-topic page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

This is why I'm asking to add it **on the on-topic page**

What I want by adding this is not about newbies that didn't read that page, but to make sure that user with close review privilege, which have more chance to have read this page, will be aware of this site exists.

Note: Programmers is not also listed while SharePoint is, maybe part of the page needs to be refreshed, or linked to a meta question that include all relevant sites that we're used to redirect here. I was sure that this question existed, but I couldn't find it.

EDIT : I found the page as i was looking for, it was on programmers.SE and is linked on their on-topic page : https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-programmers-where-else-can-i-ask

Edit : Not a duplicate i'm talking about the page on-topic not to change the off-topic flags.

Comment: The problem is we can't actually close/migrate questions to that site because it's not  part of the list of alternate SE sites appearing in the close vote dialog.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There are three problems : the option "your question belongs to another castle" disapear when we can't migrate it anymore, this lead to have question closed and redirect to a wrong SE site, which is bad IMO. But i don't know if it can be changed. Second : list of off topic site is really short if we compare to the lot of possibility that can comes on SO. Third : quite  a lot of sites are missing on the on-topic page, which probably lead to have user with close privilege not even been aware that those sites exists. This is the third point that i'm adressing.

Comment: i edited my post to add the relevant post listing every related site, it was on programmers.Se : http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-programmers-where-else-can-i-ask

Comment: That site should probably not be on the list because it would likely be flooded with erroneously migrated "Halp can't get DHCP to work" type post.

Comment: @jonrsharpe & Co. I'm talking about the page http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Not about off-topic flags....

Comment: @Pekka웃 As i said we could have a link on the on-topc page which details all related site, that's exactly what Programmers.SE have done, look at their meta post : http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-programmers-where-else-can-i-ask

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a fair solution.